# How many solutions are to the equation if there's range restriction on some numbers while some numbers must be divisible by $3$?

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

> How many solutions belonging to $\mathbb N$ are to the equation:
>   $$
> a_1+a_2+\dots +a_{10}+b_1+b_2+\dots+b_5=7
> $$
>   if $0\le a_i \le 2$ for $1\le i\le 10$ and $b_i$ is divisible by $3$ for $1\le i\le 5$?

I want to solve this using generating functions. I think we can create the function:
$$
f(a,b)=(1+x+x^2)^{10}(y^3+y^6+y^9+\dots)^5\\
=(1+x+x^2)^{10}y^{15}(1+y^2+y^3+\dots)
$$
but as far as I understand I need to find the coefficient of $a^xb^y$ such that $x+y=7$ but there's $y^{15}$ already in the expression. Is my function wrong or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot that $0$ is also divisible by $3$, so your $b_i \in\{0,3\}$. Resulting generating function should be
$$
f(x,y) = \left(1+x+x^2\right)^{10} \left(1 + y^3 + \ldots \right)^5
$$

In addition, I don't really understand why you need a 2-variable generating function. You can likely find $\left[x^7\right]g(x)$ for $g(x) = f(x,x)$.

Comment: you're right there's no need for two variables, I just did it following the format of the equation which had two variables

Comment: If we suppose that all variables are $x$ then I get that $f(x)=(\frac{1-x^3}{1-x})^{10}(\frac{1}{1-x^3})^5$ which becomes this using identities: $\sum_{k=0}^{10}{10\choose k}(-1)^kx^{3k}\cdot \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} {10+i-1\choose i}x^i\cdot \sum_{j=0}^{\infty}{5+j-1\choose j}x^{3j}$. Then there 6 possible combinations $x^{3k}\cdot x^i\cdot x^{3j}$ such that $3k+i+3j=7$. Is this correct or I made a mistake somewhere because the answer seems to be too complicated