# How to solve multiplication of $3$ generating functions?

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

I'm trying to calculate the solution to this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2780917/how-many-solutions-are-to-the-equation-if-theres-range-restriction-on-some-numb). We can convert the original two-variable generating function into this format:
$$
f(x)=(1+x+x^2)^{10}(1+x^3+x^6+\dots)^5
$$
which according to power series identities becomes:
$$
\bigg(\frac{1-x^3}{1-x}\bigg)^{10}\bigg(\frac{1}{1-x^3}\bigg)^5=\\
\sum_{k=0}^{10}{10\choose k}(-1)^kx^{3k}\cdot \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} {10+i-1\choose i}x^i\cdot \sum_{j=0}^{\infty}{5+j-1\choose j}x^{3j}
$$
In order to find the coefficient $x^7$, there're $6$ possible combinations of $x^{3k}x^ix^{3j}$ such that $3k+i+3j=7$. This seems quite complicated I'm wondering if I'm on the right track with the solution.

Comment: Seems like you power series identity can be simplified to $\big(\frac{1-x^3}{1-2x+x^2}\big)^5$.

Comment: Yes of course! Thank you I didn't see this. Didn't you mean $(\frac{(1-x^3)^5}{(1-x)^{10}})$?

Comment: Same thing $(1-2x+x^2) = (1-x)^2$